# jquery and javascript script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys i wonder if u can help me with this code to find out why it isn't working. It supose to fill out a textarea with some schema code. Help me with this i'm stuck.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("input").keyup(function() {
    updateTemplate();
});

});
var Comunity = "Comunity";

var ot = "&lt;";
var ct = "&gt;";


function updateTemplate() {

comunityText = $("#myComunity").val();
thisStreet = $("#myAddress").val();
thisCity = $("#myCity").val();
thisState = $("#myState").val();
thisZip = $("#myZip").val();
thisUrl = $("#myUrl").val();
thisImgurl = $("#myImgurl")val();
thisDescription= $("#myDescription").val();

var template = "<div itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/" + Comunity + "\">\n";
template += "\t<div itemprop=\"name\">" + comunityText + "</div>\n";

    if ($("#myLat").val() != "") {
    template += "\n\t<div itemtype=\"http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates\" itemscope=\"\" itemprop=\"geo\">\n";
        template += "\t\t<meta itemprop=\"latitude\" content=\"" + $("#myLat").val() + "\" />\n";
        template += "\t\t<meta itemprop=\"longitude\" content=\"" + $("#myLong").val() + "\" />\n";
    template += "\n\t</div>";
}

template += "\n\t<div itemtype=\"http://schema.org/PostalAddress\" itemscope=\"\" itemprop=\"address\">\n";
    template += "\t\t<div itemprop=\"streetAddress\">" + thisStreet + "</div>\n";
    template += "\t\t<div><span itemprop=\"addressLocality\">" + thisCity + "</span>, <span itemprop=\"addressRegion\">" + thisState + "</span> <span itemprop=\"postalCode\">" + thisZip + "</span></div>\n";

template += "\t</div>\n";


template +=  "</div>\n";

$("#textOut").html(template);
$("#myOut").html(template);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide more specific details. What does it currently do, and how does that differ from what you want it to do? Does it produce any errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What outcome do you want?

Comment: Also, it looks like we'll need to see the HTML that this uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> thisImgurl = $("#myImgurl")val();

There is a point missing.